# force bootstrap col-md vertical in desktop view with only css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to force bootstrap to vertical align this col in desktop view. because it's overlaping otherwise

the mess now :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1cyi.png)

so the problem fix it self if i resize the windows until it reach the mobile view (it will automaticly vertical align the div.) but i want it to be like that in any windows size.

what i trying to :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnEUl.png)

here is the catch. i can only acsess the css on that particular div.
because it's dynamically generated. and i cant change the html part.

here is what the html looks like :

```html
<ul class="subquestions-list questions-list checkbox-list list-unstyled">  
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-1">
  <li id="javatbd736732X11537X92547SQ001" class="question-item answer-item checkbox-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
   <label for="answer736732X11537X92547SQ001" class="answertext"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="736732X11537X92547SQ001" id="answer736732X11537X92547SQ001" value="Y" onclick="cancelBubbleThis(event);checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><input type="hidden" name="java736732X11537X92547SQ001" id="java736732X11537X92547SQ001" value="">Grundlagen der Informatik</label>
    </div>
  </li>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-1">
  <li id="javatbd736732X11537X92547SQ002" class="question-item answer-item checkbox-item">
   <div class="checkbox"><label for="answer736732X11537X92547SQ002" class="answertext"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="736732X11537X92547SQ002" id="answer736732X11537X92547SQ002" value="Y" onclick="cancelBubbleThis(event);checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)"><input type="hidden" name="java736732X11537X92547SQ002" id="java736732X11537X92547SQ002" value="">Theoretische Informatik</label></div>
  </li>
 </div>
</div>
  </ul>
```

i can also acsess it with javascript using dom manipulation. but i dont think it helps that much.

please help me!
thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion ! sorry still new to StackOverflow (as a user)